# Android: tabs don't fill parent with Holo theme?

Tags: android

The below code creates a View with 4 tabs.  Using the default theme (no theme defined in the androidmanifest.xml), I get the first image, in which the tabs grow equally to fill the available space.  If I set theme to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo"`, I get the second image, in which the tabwidget (with the green background) still fills the parent's width, but the tabs do not grow to fill the tabwidget.

Any ideas of how I can get the first result while using Theme.Holo?

[image]

[image]

```
public class TempProjActivity extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(new MyTabHost(this));
    }

    private class MyTabHost extends TabHost
    {
        public MyTabHost(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, null);

            setId(android.R.id.tabhost);

            TabWidget widget = new TabWidget(getContext());
            widget.setId(android.R.id.tabs);
            widget.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            widget.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);

            FrameLayout layout = new FrameLayout(getContext());
            layout.setId(android.R.id.tabcontent);
            layout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

            LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
            linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new TabHost.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
            linearLayout.addView(widget);
            linearLayout.addView(layout);

            addView(linearLayout);

            setup();

            TabSpec spec = newTabSpec("tab1");
            spec.setIndicator("", getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            spec.setContent(new TabContentFactory() 
            {
                @Override
                public View createTabContent(String tag) 
                {
                    return new View(getContext());
                }
            });
            addTab(spec);

            spec = newTabSpec("tab2");
            spec.setIndicator("", getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            spec.setContent(new TabContentFactory() 
            {
                @Override
                public View createTabContent(String tag) 
                {
                    return new View(getContext());
                }
            });
            addTab(spec);

            spec = newTabSpec("tab3");
            spec.setIndicator("", getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            spec.setContent(new TabContentFactory() 
            {
                @Override
                public View createTabContent(String tag) 
                {
                    return new View(getContext());
                }
            });
            addTab(spec);

            spec = newTabSpec("tab5");
            spec.setIndicator("", getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
            spec.setContent(new TabContentFactory() 
            {
                @Override
                public View createTabContent(String tag) 
                {
                    return new View(getContext());
                }
            });
            addTab(spec);
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT:

If I add the below code at the end of MyTabHost's constructor, I get the below image.  However the icon is still not centered in the tabs, and it doesn't seem like a particularly safe piece of code.

Any idea of better options than this? Or opinions on if this is a reasonable option?

[image]

```
        post(new Runnable() 
        {

            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < widget.getChildCount(); i++)
                {
                    widget.getChildAt(i).getLayoutParams().width = getWidth()/widget.getChildCount();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I am having the same issue. Have you tried testing on a real device at all?